# Send email XAMP + sendmail + PHP + GMAIL

Tags: php, xampp, gmail, localhost, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email using xampp (localhost) and sendmail, using gmail but probably Google performed some changed on privacy setting and I'm not able to use it with the definitions found on other posts.
I've already disabled the 2 step validation and allow all apps to access (on Google Account).

I have the following information on my computer:

```
sendmail.ini
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mygmailpassword
default_domain=localhost
debug_logfile=debug.log
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=localhost
```

And

```
php.ini
sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

And

```
<?php

    $message = "Test";
    $headers = "From: emaik_from@gmail.com";
    mail("email_to@gmail.com", "Testing", $message, $headers);

    echo "worked";

    ?>
```

I've tried more examples but I always get:

```
15/12/10 12:19:13 : Socket Error # 10061<EOL>Connection refused.
```

I've tried as well with 465 and 25 ports
Do you guys have some ideas?

Thank you!
João Corrêa

Comment: Your ISP is likely blocking those ports. Are you using a home internet connection?

Comment: Hello,I'm using a corporate connection.

Comment: You should talk to IT and ask them if they're blocking those ports.